# Is there a baked in way to do Orderby or is this still state of the art for EF4.X

Tags: c#, entity-framework

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

I looking to use EF with jqGrid and minimize plumbing. Therefore it interests me to find a generalized solution similiar to what Scott suggests. I am curious if this has been baked into EF or if this is still this is still the best way.

Specifically:
entity.Orderby("fieldName");

Comment: That article covers a lot.  What specifically are you asking about?

Comment: Passing a field via a string into a orderby via the dynamic query lib in the 3.5 samples. I could introduce this. But there may be a way to do the same thing with EF 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the Dynamic Expression API NuGet package. This will allow you to express your query parameters as strings (in the way that Scott Gu shows).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing baked in to Linq.  The [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) method still takes a `Func<>` as the first argument.

However, [`ObjectQuery.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358828%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) DOES take a string parameter, so if you are using EF and can use `ObjectQuery` objects instead of `IEnumerable`/`IQueryable` interfaces then it may be possible.